# Ask turtles to change colour and stop when they meet other turtles Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have two turtles of colour 'green' and colour 'blue'. I would like when the green turtles meet the blue turtles, the blue turtles turn white and stop moving while the green turtles continue moving randomly. Here is my code, I did but it is gives an error of **Expected a literal value** and is not doing returning the expected results. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
ask turtles with [color = green]
  [if any? other turtles-here with [color = blue]
    [set turtles with [color = blue] [color = white]
]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `ask` (instruct) the turtles. The keyword `with` subsets the correct turtles but you need to `set` a variable, not `set` a turtleset. Also, '=' is used for evaluation (comparing), not for assigning values. I think you want this:

```
ask turtles with [color = green]
[ if any? other turtles-here with [color = blue]
  [ ask turtles-here with [color = blue]
    [ set color white
    ]
  ]
]
```

Note that I had to write `turtles-here` again, or all the blue turtles would turn white. A more readable way that also reduces errors is to set up a temporary variable (using `let`) for the relevant turtles.

```
ask turtles with [color = green]
[ let changers other turtles-here with [color = blue]
  if any? changers
  [ ask changers
    [ set color white
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Ask a new question. At the very least, you will have to show us the code you are using to move the turtles as well as whatever you are doing to try to make them stop moving.